# Breaking List of list to a single list java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a java method that returns below output:

```
List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futureResponselist;
```

How can I construct a single list from this data? As I have to iterate the final output and do some operation with the "string" param that is present inside.

I want all the string values present inside these lists in a final single list.

It should be as: `List<String>`  My futureResponselist size is 3.so the conversion TO List should happen in nonblocking way

Comment: Are you going to use only string values?

Comment: i need the  out put as List<string> Fatih  --@Fatih. Basically every data inside the list is  as string accountId+":"+status;Ya..i want only the string values  @Fatih

Answer (score 3):

You have many ways to do this. To flatten nested lists for Java 8 and higher, you can use a structure like below to do it functionally. If you want to process in parallel you can use `Collection::parallelStream` instead of `Collection::stream`.

```
List<String> onlyStringValues = futureResponseList.stream()
                                            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                                            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Faith -it will be non blacking correct?So, my batch size is 3 and i have called supplyAsync method thrice.so,the futureResponseList  size is  3.I dont want the main thread should get blocked till the 1st batch is completed .It  will be doing in non blocking way correct?

Comment: @hatefAlipoor Thanks, I didn't know that. I edited my answer in a different way.

Comment: @Debo Looking through the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376577/why-main-thread-is-not-waiting-for-other-async-processthreads-to-complete-all) may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple: Iterate the outer [`list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) using an enhanced `for` loop, [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--) the inner list from the [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) and [add all](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) the elements to the result list.

```java
List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futureResponselist = ...

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (CompletableFuture<List<String>> future : futureResponselist)
    result.addAll(future.get());
```

Comment: Hi  Andress,future.get() is blocking call correct..I  dont want it to get blocked.my futureResponselist is 3.so the conversion should happen in non blocking way

Comment: @Debo Question says you want **all** the values, so you *have* to block to wait for them to be available. Of course, if you don't want to block, simply add `if (future.isDone())`, so it skips future that aren't ready yet. That should be so obvious that I'm baffled why you didn't figure that out yourself, unless of course you haven't even looked at the javadoc of `CompletableFuture` is see what it supports. Please do that now, so you don't ask questions you already have readily available answers to with a click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code, if the order of list is not important consider parallelizsing it

```
List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futureResponselist = new ArrayList<>();
futureResponselist.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> List.of("1" , "2")));
futureResponselist.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> List.of("3" , "4", "5")));
futureResponselist.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> List.of("6")));
List<String> result = futureResponselist
        .stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

update: more general approach it is adopted from the `Modern Java in Action`

```
Executor executor =
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futureResponselist = new ArrayList<>();
futureResponselist.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> List.of("1" , "2"), executor));
futureResponselist.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> List.of("3" , "4", "5"), executor));
futureResponselist.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> List.of("6"), executor));

List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futureResult = futureResponselist
        .stream()
        .map(future -> future.thenApply(Function.identity())) // do some processing with list here we just return it but you can do something else
        .map(future -> future.thenApply(Function.identity()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
futureResult
                    .parallelStream()
                    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .forEach(System.out::println); // do something when the result is ready here we just print it
```

Comment: Almost there, but question specifies that the result should be a `List<String>`, not the printing of the elements.

Comment: my futureResponselist is 3.so the conversion should happen in non blocking way..@hatef ..my requirement is ..after get thsi LIst<String>,i have iterate this final list and with every element present i have post it to  do some operation..

Comment: hI @hatef, yes i have done in parallel way ..so my  batch size was 3.so supplyasyn  was called thrice and every call returned  one CompletableFuture<List<String>>> ..so size of futureResponselist is 3

Comment: @Debo I update the answer, hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Iterate futureResponselist and then iterate list of String for each CompletableFuture and add the string to list declared outside of both for loop

```
List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futureResponselist;

// List of string to store combined result
List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();

for (CompletableFuture com : futureResponselist) {
    for (String string : com.getYourListOfString()) {
        mergedList.add();
    }
}
```

Comment: really sorry to ask again as i have started new in java:here com.getYourListOfString()) what to pass? not getting the syntex.how to pur each on CompletableFuture object.How will is get the list of string from CompletableFuture object

Comment: Thanks a lot @hatef Alipoor :-)it helped a lot.My problem looks to be solved