# How to call independent functions parallel and throw exception if one fails using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, future, completable-future

I am try to do something like

```
Optional<Order> orderDetails = orderRepository.findById(orderId);
if (orderDetails.isEmpty())
    throw new OrderNotFoundException("Order not found!");

Optional<User> UserDetails = userRepository.findById(userId);
if (UserDetails.isEmpty())
    throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found!");

List<OrderItem> ItemDetailsList = orderItemRepository.findByOrderIdOrderByItemIdAsc(orderId);
```

Where I want to call these three Services methods together in a non-blocking way, but I want to throw error if any one of those call fails and dont proceed furthur.
If all of the above works, then execute the later logic.

I am thinking of using `allOff()` then after that use get on the Futures and do the above logic of throwing error when the Optional is empty?

Is there better way of doing it ? *i.e* if one of them fails and others are still running, throw error and abort the other running tasks.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33783992/11748454) might provide what you are looking for.

Comment: you could mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

`CompletableFuture` is the wrong tool for the job here. And the main problem is that you want:

> "...throw error and abort the other running tasks"

If you read what `CompletableFuture::cancel` documentation says, you will see that:

> mayInterruptIfRunning – this value **has no effect** in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

So, even if you call `cancel`, this will not interrupt your tasks, they will still continue to completition. As such, your fundamental requirement can not be met.

There is a way with creating a custom pool of threads for that `CompletableFuture` that you want to cancel and shut down the pool, [as an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64743332/stopping-a-thread-in-java-completablefuture-after-timeout/64815403#64815403). But this is not trivial to do and your threads need to respond to interrupts properly.